# Is this a sum of two binomial random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

So I'm a math tutor and one of my students approached me with this problem:

A grocery store has six checkout lanes: four normal lanes, which are in use on average 80% of the time, and two express lanes, which are in use 60% of the time. If you choose to checkout at a randomly selected time, what is the probability that there is precisely one lane (of either kind) open?

Here is how I directed the student to its solution.

Suppose there are *X* normal lanes open and *Y* express lanes open at some randomly chosen time. IF we can assume that lanes are independently occupied (which is a stretch) then $ X \sim B(4,\frac{1}{5})$ and $Y \sim B(2,\frac{2}{5})$. We need to compute $P(X+Y=1).$ Using additivity and independence, we get$$ P(X+Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=0)+P(X=0)P(Y=1) \approx33.4\%$$

Evidently this problem was marked totally incorrect on this student's homework and I would like to know why. If anyone could help I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem trying to say find the probability that one of each is open simultaneously? Because I don't see anything wrong with your method, so I think the only place you could have possibly gone wrong is in doing the math with the binomials.

Comment: The professor expects polished mathematics, so I tried to frame the solution with binomials. If you read the sentence without acknowledging (of either kind) the question requires precisely one lane open out of the six. I was thinking that, maybe, the question was saying 80% is $P(X=4)$ and 60% is $P(Y=2),$ but I am not sure.

Comment: Were we to do this with Binomials (which I'm not 100% convinced is the intended approach), it seems to me that $X\sim\mathrm{Bin}(4,0.8)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Bin}(2,0.6).$ That is, each of the normal lanes are in use on average 80% of the time and similarly for the express lanes.

Comment: If you're saying $X \sim B(4,0.8)$ and $Y \sim B(2,0.6),$ then $X+Y=1$  refers to the event that there is exactly one lane *in use,* not open. The question wants to find the probability that exactly one lane is open.

Comment: If you read the question as "open" meaning "not currently in use" then the desired answer may be $P(X+Y=6-1) = P(X=4)P(Y=1)+P(X=3)P(Y=2)$

Comment: Exactly. The only difference in my solution versus yours is that your random variables count the number of "failures" (lanes being in use) while mine count the number of successes (lanes not currently in use). Obviously if $X$ and $Y$ count the number of lanes currently in use, the event that exactly one lane is open means $X=4,Y=1$ (exclusive) or $X=3,Y=2.$ Either way, you still get $33.4 \%$, but, according to this professor, that answer is completely wrong. Like 0/15 points on the assignment.